# The default constructor is already defined

Tags: flutter, dart

When trying to declare `CardView` class in my Flutter application, I get the error `The default constructor is already defined`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled5/model/card_model.dart';



class CardView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardView({Key? key, required this.card}) : super(key: key);

  final CardModel card;
  

  CardView(this.card) : super();

  @override
  _CardViewState createState() => _CardViewState();
}
```

Comment: Function overloading is not supported in dart

Answer (score 1):

The class `CardView` is defined with two constructors which is not allowed in dart.

**Remove the second constructor, as shown the line below, from the code shown above.**

```dart
CardView(this.card) : super();
```